# If $A$ commutes with $A^*A$, does it follow that $A$ is normal?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, solution-verification, positive-definite, normal-operator

We are working finite-dimensional complex vector space:

> If $A$ commutes with $A^*A$, does it follow that $A$ is normal?

Could you please verify my proof:

1. Since $A^*A$ is positive, let $A^*A = \bigoplus_i^m\lambda_i E_i$ be a spectral form, and let vector space $V = \bigoplus_i^m V_i$ be a direct sum, where $V_i$ is an eigen space of $\lambda_i$.
2. Liner transformation $A = \bigoplus_i^m A_i$ is reducible by $V_i$.
   There are multiple ways to prove this. One way is to use the fact that $E_i$ is a projection which is idempotent and which commutes with $A$. Then $A = A\cdot I = A\cdot(\bigoplus_i^m E_i) = A\cdot(\bigoplus_i^m E_i^2) = \bigoplus_i^m E_i A E_i = \bigoplus_i^m A_i$. Another way is to show that each $V_i$ is an invariant under $A$: let $x \in V_i$ such that $A^*Ax = \lambda_i x$ then $A^*A(Ax) = A (A^*Ax) = A\lambda_i x = \lambda_i(Ax)$ and $Ax$ is an eigen vector of $\lambda_i$ and $Ax \in V_i$.
3. Now that we know that $A$ is reducible, $A^*A = \bigoplus_i^m\lambda_i E_i = \bigoplus_i^m{A_i}^*A_i$ and ${A_i}^*A_i = \lambda_i E_i = \lambda_i I$ on all $V_i$. And if $\lambda_i \neq 0$, $\frac{A_i}{\sqrt \lambda_i}$ is isometry and therefore $A$ is normal. Note: $E_i$ is a projection and it's restriction to $V_i$ is identity $I$. $\lambda_i >= 0$ is positive. Definition of isometry $U^*U = I$. If $\lambda_j = 0$ for some $j$ then $V_j = ker A^*A = ker A$ and $A_j = 0$.

Comment: You should state at the outset that you're working in a finite-dimensional (complex?) vector space. Why is $A^*A$ necessarily positive?

Comment: For me, it looks fine.

Comment: I don't understand your third step.

Comment: @Nathanael-skrepek I've added some comments.

Comment: You don't want to divide by $\lambda_i$ when it is possible that $\lambda_i = 0$.

Comment: @Robert-israel thank you. I have amended my answer.

Comment: Note: a very short proof comes from writing out your equality, left multiplying by $A^*$ then taking the trace, and confirming this implies the (squared) frobenius norm of $A^*A - AA^*$ is zero.

Comment: @user8675309 do you mean showing that $tr[(A^*A - AA^*)^*(A^*A - AA^*)] = 0$?

Comment: Yes.  This is the most direct route.  An equivalent but more pleasant approach is to observe  $\text{trace}\Big(\big(A^*  A\big)^2 \Big)   \geq  \text{trace}\Big(\big( A^*  A\big)^*\big(  A A^*\big)  \Big)= \text{trace}\Big(\big( A^2\big)^* \big( A^2\big)  \Big)$, and then consider the equality conditions of Cauchy Schwarz