# $R$ is a positive definite symmetric operator with $R^{-1}=B$. Then prove $AJ=JA$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A^TA$ is diagonalizable  and has positive eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_{2n}$ .Where $A$ is an antisymmetric matrix. Hence we can write $A^TA=B\cdot\text{diag}(\lambda_1,..,\lambda_{2n})B^{-1}$ for some square matrix $B$ of order $2n$ .
> Let $R=\sqrt{A^TA}=B\cdot\text{diag}{(\sqrt{\lambda_1},..,\sqrt{\lambda_{2n}}})B^{-1}$. Let $J=R^{-1}A$. Then $R$ is a positive definite symmetric operator. $R^{-1}=B\cdot\text{diag} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_1}},...,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_{2n}}}\right)B^{-1}$.
> Then prove $AJ=JA$

---

Since $A$ is skew symmetric so $A^T=-A$, so $R^2=-A^2$, So

$AJ=AR^{-1}A=A(R^{-2})RA=A(R^2)^{-1}RA=A(-A^2)^{-1}RA \\=(-A^{-1})RA=-A^{-1}RA=-(R^{-1}A)^{-1}A=-J^{-1}A\\$

Suppose $AJ=JA$ then $AR^{-1}A=R^{-1}AA \Rightarrow AR^{-1}=R^{-1}A \Rightarrow RA=AR$ . So we have to prove $R$ commute with $A$. But how ??

Comment: Work over $\mathbb C$ and unitarilly diagonalize $A \implies AR=RA$ because both are diagonal. Then show unitary conjugation doesn't change commutativity. If you prefer working over $\mathbb R$, you can show $A$ is orthogonally similar to a block diagonal matrix where blocks are at most $2\times 2$ and run essentially the same proof. This problem is about **Polar Decomposition** and the fact that $A$ *is normal is essential* here, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696363/let-a-mathbbrn-to-mathbbrn-be-an-invertible-linear-map-b2-ata-let/3697307#3697307