# For a polar decompoistion $A=BJ$, the matrices $A$ and $B$ commute

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $A$ is an invertible real $n\times n$ matrix, and consider its (unique) polar decomposition $A=BJ$ where $B$ is positive definite symmetric and $J$ is orthogonal. Is it true that $AB=BA$?

Actually I am reading Audin, Damian's book *Morse Theory and Floer Homology* and the above statement is assumed in p.141.
To be more precise, for a symplectic vector space $(E,\omega)$ with an inner product $(,)$, the matrix $A$ is determined by $(X,AY)=\omega(X,Y)$.

Comment: Your book seems to have a common fallacy.  Ref e.g. my addendum here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696363/let-a-mathbbrn-to-mathbbrn-be-an-invertible-linear-map-b2-ata-let/3697307#3697307

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is not true. For $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 &1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ we have $$B^2=AA^T=\begin{pmatrix}2 &1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ and $AB^2\neq B^2A.$

The claim is true if the matrix $A$ is symmetric, or more generally normal, i.e. $AA^T=A^TA.$

Comment: But your $A$ is not invertible

Comment: I have corrected