# Prove that $B$ is normal

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $B$ be a complex invertible matrix such that $B^*B^2B^*=B+B^*$. Prove that $B$ is normal.

I was only able to prove that $BB^*$, $B^*B$ commute, so $BB^*$, $B^*B$, $B+B^*$ are simultaneously diagonalizable (and also $B+B^*$ is positive definite). I know that the problem works also for $B$ ordinary, but that problem becomes easy if we solve it for $B$ invertible. Anyway, I tried solving this for a long time, and nothing works. Any tips would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the problem works for $B$ ordinary"? And why is it easy in the case that $B$ is invertible? Note the problem does stipulate that $B$ is invertible

Comment: By "ordinary", do you mean "having real number entries"?

Comment: I did not meant that it is easy when $B$ is invertible; I just said that IF we prove this problem for $B$ invertible, than we actually see easily that it stands for every  matrix $B$ (this what I meant by ordinary). It was just a remark.

Comment: That makes sense now, thank you

Comment: You can rewrite the equation in the forms
$$B^*B = BB^{-*}B^{-1} + B^{-1}\\
BB^* = B^{-1}B^{-*}B + B^{-1}$$
I'm not sure if that's helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using OP's observation about $BB^*$ and $B^*B$ commuting, left multiply $B^*B^2B^*=B+B^*$ by $(B^*B)$ to get
$(B^*B)B + (B^*B)B^* = (B^*B)B^*B^2B^* = B^*B^2B^*(B^*B)=B(B^*B) + B^*(B^*B)$

then left multiply by $B^*$ and take the trace
$\text{trace}\Big(B^*(B^*B)B\Big) + \text{trace}\Big(B^*(B^*B)B^*\Big)= \text{trace}\Big(B^*B(B^*B)\Big) + \text{trace}\Big(B^*B^*(B^*B)\Big)$
$\implies \text{trace}\Big((BB^*)(B^*B)\Big) = \text{trace}\Big(B^*(B^*B)B\Big) = \text{trace}\Big((B^*B)^2\Big) $ [cyclic property of trace]
$\implies B^*B=BB^*$ by Cauchy-Schwarz; equivalently the trace equality shows $\Big\Vert BB^* -B^*B\Big\Vert_F^2 = 0$

**addendum: simultaneous diagonalization proof**
write $B= H + S$, where $H$ is Hermitian and $S$ is skew-Hermitian
OP has observed that $BB^*$, $B^*B$ and $B+B^* = 2H$ are simultaneously diagonalizable by some unitary $U$.
$B^*B -BB^* = \big(H^2 - S^2 -SH +HS\big)-\big(H^2 - S^2 +SH -HS\big)= 2\big(HS -SH\big)$

conjugating by $U^{*}$ gives
$U^*\big(B^*B -BB^*\big)U =  2\big((U^* HU) (U^*SU) -(U^* SU) (U^* HU)\big)=  2\big(\Sigma (U^*SU) -(U^* SU) \Sigma \big)$
where $\Sigma$ is a real diagonal matrix (in fact non-negative).  The left hand side is a real diagonal matrix and the right hand side has a purely imaginary diagonal $\implies U^*\big(B^*B -BB^*\big)U = \mathbf 0 \implies B^*B = BB^*$

*remark:*
The fact that $U$ is unitary is of little consequence.  We could instead observe that
$\Sigma (U^{-1}SU) -(U^{-1} SU) \Sigma$  has its $k$th diagonal component given by $\sigma_{k,k}\cdot(U^{-1} SU)_{k,k}-(U^{-1} SU)_{k,k}\cdot \sigma_{k,k} = 0$

Comment: Wow, thank you. I actually tried at first to show that $tr((B^*B-BB^*)^2)=0$ since it is generally an useful strategy in this kind of problems, but I gave up on it pretty fast. I really thought it won't work here, but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: a standard criterion for normality is $B(B^*B) = (B^*B)B$, ref e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3522676/if-a-commutes-with-aa-does-it-follow-that-a-is-normal ,  and the first 2 lines above recover that equality, albeit with extra $B^*(B^*B)$ and $(B^*B)B^*$ terms involved -- however my suggested proof in that link runs identically thanks to the cyclic property of trace.

Comment: Yeah, I know this criterion, and in fact I tried to create here a proof similar to my proof for that criterion. The original statement for this problem was indeed for $A$ an arbitrary matrix, but since $A$ is similar to the matrix $diag(0,B)$ for an invertible $B$, I posted the question like this thinking it would make it easier. In the case of that criterion, the problem becomes trivial because if $B$ is invertible, we get $BB^*=B^*B$, and it's done, but here this fact is apparently of no use. Thank you again.

Comment: I added a proof via simultaneous diagonalization as an addendum